# UI Testing, how to access passwords locally and in a devops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ui-testing

I want to have my UI Tests access different user accounts in our staging environment.

However, I don’t want to include the username and password in a config file in our git repository.

In our devops pipeline I’ve previously replaced tags with environmental variables in a config file as a pipelines task.

But I can’t do this locally as I don’t have a pipeline to run tasks. Even if I did I’d still need to get access to passwords.

I’m using a Mac for dev locally and our pipeline. Also C# / Xamarin.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the username and password in a file. You can upload the file as secure file in azure devops instead of including it in your git repository. See document [Secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops).

Go to your Project portal-->Library under Pipelines-->Secure files

[image]

Then you can use [Download Secure File task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline to download the file and access to the username and password.

You can also try defining the password as a [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) in azure pipeline. Then you can access to the password in pipeline by reference to the secret variable. Please check out the document to learn how to map the secret variable and use it in a task.

If your UI testing is automated by coded.  You define the username and password as the pipeline variables or as environment variables on local machine. Then you can access to the [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0) in your codes.

Comment: great, this is the best solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

In your pipeline, rather than have them be read as part of the pipeline, can your test suite read them from the environment variables?

Then locally you can also store them in environment variables and read them in the test suite as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wouldn’t call the Test Explorer in Visual Studio a suite, don’t think it has the functionality to cater for environmental variables.

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping for a mechanism where I could keep all my secrets in one place, without having to maintain 2 places. Also I’m at the start of the process and am unsure if I’ll need to have access to data for different tests. So I may end up with some kind of database. At the moment I’m using json, where I don’t commit my local user name / password until I can progress, but I will need to change this.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a few options

Create a secrets file

Key=[Blank]
Key=[Blank]

Commit/push so everyone has a template copy

Then `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` so when you add the secrets they don’t get pushed.
This might be a pain if you need to add more at a later date.

—-

Guest Post: Securing and Versioning Xamarin Apps with Mobile.BuildTools
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/securing-versioning-xamarin-apps-with-mobilebuildtools/

Mobile.BuildTools
https://github.com/dansiegel/Mobile.BuildTools